# Error while linking libconfig with c++ using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

Here is the cmake file that i am using

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (midasd)

set (midas VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set (midas VERSION_MINOR 0)
set (midas VERSION_REVISION 1)

find_library(libconfig libconfig)

add_executable(midasd src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(midasd "${libconfig_LIBS}")
```

The problem i am facing is undefined reference for `config_init`. The main function is as follows

```
#include <libconfig.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        midas::midasCtx *container = new midas::midasCtx(argc,argv);
        config_t cfg;
        config_init(&cfg);
        return 0;
}
```

Where am i going wrong with `CMAKE` ?

Comment: Print `libconfig_LIBS` and see whether it has any value before `target_link_libraries`

Comment: it's coming out empty

Comment: Then you have the answer. You can check `find_library` and I believe `"${libconfig_LIBS}"` should be `"${libconfig}"`

Comment: For future reference, what Viet is stepping you through is called _debugging_.

Answer (score 2):

Actually on non-windows systems the `libconfig` is recognized as simply `-lconfig` not `-llibconfig`in linking argument. The CMakeLists.txt should contain

`target_link_libraries(my_project config)`

[Source](https://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html#Using-the-Library-from-a-C-Program)

A Cmake-Example can be seen [in the examples section](https://github.com/hyperrealm/libconfig/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/CMakeLists.txt) of the project.

Answer (score 0):

This manual(https://hyperrealm.github.io/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html) says " To link with the library, specify ‘-lconfig++’ as an argument to the linker. "

So I fixed like following code and build was completed.

```
target_link_libraries(my_project config++)
```